# Remove QGIS watermark on QGIS Server tiles

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

I am trying to set up QGIS Server in a leaflet client. Everything works fine, except that I get a QGIS logo watermark on each tile, which obviously is not so great.

[image: WMS result]
Here is my WMS request:

http://0.0.0.0/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?
map=map.qgs&
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.3.0&
REQUEST=GetMap&
BBOX=37,-122,38,-121.7&
CRS=EPSG:4326&
WIDTH=722&
HEIGHT=352&
LAYERS=map&
STYLES=default&
FORMAT=image/png&
DPI=96&
TRANSPARENT=true

I have searched everywhere but I can't seem to find where to remove it.

Did anyone face the same problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anyone encounters the same problem: I installed QGIS Server with a tutorial that made me install HelloServer. It is a nice little tool with which you have quick confirmation that your server is set up.

However it puts this QGIS logo in all your WMS responses. Just **delete the plugin**, and everything will return to normal.

If you want to keep the plugin but only get rid of the watermark, the file responsible for it is [this one](https://github.com/elpaso/qgis-helloserver/blob/master/filters/WatermarkFilter.py).

Comment: Glad that you got it to work! Did you remove [this python module](https://github.com/elpaso/qgis-helloserver/blob/master/filters/WatermarkFilter.py) to get rid of the watermarks? If so, please edit and accept your own answer, it'll help those who will hit the same problem in the future :)

Comment: I removed the whole plugin since I did not need it, but getting rid of the one you linked to is indeed sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

The Apache configuration you find [here](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_server_support.html#qgis-server-installation-on-debian-ubuntu) enables server plugins :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/qgis-server-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/qgis-server-access.log combined

  # Longer timeout for WPS... default = 40
  FcgidIOTimeout 120
  FcgidInitialEnv LC_ALL "en_US.UTF-8"
  FcgidInitialEnv PYTHONIOENCODING UTF-8
  FcgidInitialEnv LANG "en_US.UTF-8"
  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_DEBUG 1
  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_FILE /tmp/qgis-000.log
  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_LEVEL 0
  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_PLUGINPATH "/opt/qgis-server/plugins"

  # Needed for QGIS HelloServer plugin HTTP BASIC auth
  <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
      RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
  </IfModule>

  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
      AllowOverride All
      Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
      # for apache2 > 2.4
      Require all granted
      #Allow from all
  </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

You can comment out this line to disable plugins :

```
#FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_PLUGINPATH "/opt/qgis-server/plugins"
```

And comment out this part if you use plugins but not the HelloServer one :

```
  # Needed for QGIS HelloServer plugin HTTP BASIC auth
  #<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  #    RewriteEngine on
  #    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
  #    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
  #</IfModule>
```